# Python - Convert string representation of date to ISO 8601

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

In Python, how can I convert a string like this:

> Thu, 16 Dec 2010 12:14:05 +0000

to ISO 8601 format, while keeping the timezone?

Please note that the orginal date is string, and the output should be string too, not `datetime` or something like that.

I have no problem to use third parties libraries, though.

Comment: What is the source of the string?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Using [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil):

```
import dateutil.parser as parser
text = 'Thu, 16 Dec 2010 12:14:05 +0000'
date = parser.parse(text)
print(date.isoformat())
# 2010-12-16T12:14:05+00:00
```

Comment: how would i get the time zone (z) at the end of this?

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654578/python-utc-datetime-objects-iso-format-doesnt-include-z-zulu-or-zero-offset

Answer (score 35):

Python inbuilt [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) package has build in method to convert a datetime object to isoformat. Here is a example:

```
>>>from datetime import datetime
>>>date = datetime.strptime('Thu, 16 Dec 2010 12:14:05', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
>>>date.isoformat()
```

output is

```
'2010-12-16T12:14:05'
```

I wrote this answer primarily for people, who work in UTC and doesn't need to worry about time-zones. You can strip off last 6 characters to get that string.

Python 2 doesn't have very good internal library support for timezones, for more details and solution you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13182163/4453633) on stackoverflow, which mentions usage of 3rd party libraries similar to accepted answer.

Comment: Where is the time-zone qualifier (Z in this case)?

Comment: it's not necessarily `Z` in this case. The datetime object in `date` is offset-naive so there shouldn't be any timezone qualifier at the end.

Comment: you could make it aware like so
`datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()` which would result with timezone of +00:00 which is equivalent to Z