# Python 2.7 how parse a date with format 2014-05-01 18:10:38-04:00

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to parse this datetime string, without success yet, how can I get it?

```
d = '2014-05-01 18:10:38-04:00'
datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S-%Z')

ValueError: time data '2014-05-01 18:10:38-04:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z'
```

Comment: Looking at the docs, %Z only matches things like: (empty), UTC, EST, CST

Comment: %z is supposed to match: (empty), +0000, -0400, +1030.  Except %z doesn't work for me when I try strptime ("bad directive, format").  I don't see anything in the docs to handle the TZ format that includes a colon.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The string format isn't the same..

Comment: from this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609259/converting-string-to-datetime-object-in-python it seems "strptime doesn't always support %z".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try iso8601 lib? first install it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/

Then:

```
    import iso8601
    mydate = '2014-05-01 18:10:38-04:00'
    iso8601.parse_date(mydate)

Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 1, 18, 10, 38, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '-04:00'>)
```

Comment: %timeit iso8601.parse_date(mydate) is 100000 loops, best of 3: 12.3 us per loop VS 71.9 us per loop using python-dateutil, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`python-dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) module:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> d = '2014-05-01 18:10:38-04:00'
>>> parser.parse(d)
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 1, 18, 10, 38, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))
```

Also see:

- [How to parse dates with -0400 timezone string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python)
- [How to convert a timezone aware string to datetime in python without dateutil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182075/how-to-convert-a-timezone-aware-string-to-datetime-in-python-without-dateutil)