# datetime: conversion from string with timezone name not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, timezone, python-datetime

I have the following string `"2017-03-30 08:25:00CET"` which I want to convert to a datetime tz-aware object.

According [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182075/how-to-convert-a-timezone-aware-string-to-datetime-in-python-without-dateutil), from python 3.2 it can be done using only `datetime` module. In addition, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), I see

> ```
> %z |  UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the object is naive). |  (empty), +0000, -0400, +1030
> %Z |  Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive).                        |  (empty), UTC, EST, CST
> ```

So I try the following

```
datetime.strptime(dep_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z')
```

I do not get any error, but then the object I get is not tz-aware

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 8, 25)
```

On the other hand, if I convert my string to `"2017-03-30 08:25:00+0200"` and then convert it to an object with

`datetime.strptime(dep_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')`

I do get a tz-aware datetime:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 8, 25, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)))
```

Any ideas of why it works with `%z` but not with `%Z`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Relevant for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703546/parsing-date-time-string-with-timezone-abbreviated-name-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones. 
Timezone names (such as `cet`) are ambiguous. 
Your second example works because you specifically give the timezone offset `+0200`. use the parser within dateutil, or manually specify your timezone using tzinfo().

Comment: Using Python 3.6, I get a `ValueError: time data '2017-03-30 08:25:00CET' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z'` from executing `datetime.strptime("2017-03-30 08:25:00CET", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z')`, which differs from what you say.

Comment: @CharlesMorris , thanks for the links. I found the 2nd specially interesting. To me it does not make sense that in the documentation the possibility of using timezone names is given, but then it does not work because it is ambiguous.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue22377

Comment: @martineau , strange... I am using python 3.5.2. and do not get any error. I just copy-pasted your line in my shell, and it works as I described.

Comment: This is a known bug described here: 
http://bugs.python.org/issue22377

Comment: @martineau , for me it does not make any difference if having "UTC" or "CET" at the end. I tried both and get not error, but in both cases as result I get a naive datetime object `datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 8, 25)`

Comment: J0ANMM: My interpretation of the docs wasn't exactly correct, only UTC avoids the error (EST and CST aren't acceptable). @CharlesMorris must be correct that this is bug.

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the information given by [tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects), the `%Z` does not work the way that you feed in a string like `"UTC"` and it will return a datetime instance with the correct timezone.

[pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) provides a possible solution to your problem. However, the documentation says, that there is no guarentee that your timezone will be recognized by datetime and recommends working with UTC as long as possible.

Solution using `pytz`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
dep_dt = '2017-03-30 08:25:00CET'
dt = datetime.strptime(dep_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z')
timezone(dep_dt[19:]).localize(dt)
```

Out:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 8, 25, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'CET' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

Comment: Does that mean that the documentation from `datetime` is just wrong?

Comment: At least it is not very clear. There is a note explaining the behavior, but this does not make it clear either in my opinon: "%Z

    If tzname() returns None, %Z is replaced by an empty string. Otherwise %Z is replaced by the returned value, which must be a string.

Changed in version 3.2: When the %z directive is provided to the strptime() method, an aware datetime object will be produced. The tzinfo of the result will be set to a timezone instance"

Comment: I added a solution using pytz now.

Comment: If I run your code on Python 3.8.5, I get ValueError: time data '2017-03-30 08:25:00CET' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z'. I remember there is a change from earlier version..