# converting between timezones (format same instance in time) in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, timezone

I have a list of timestamps which look like so:

```
time_list=['2016-10-01T00:00:00+01:00','2016-10-01T23:00:00+00:00','2016-10-01T22:00:00+02:00',..]
```

I would like to apply a magic function to this list which gets them all in `+00:00` timezone - this should result in (all timestamps should correctly adjusted to the `+00:00` format):

```
ret_list=['2016-10-01T23:00:00+00:00','2016-10-01T23:00:00+00:00','2016-10-01T23:00:00+00:00',..]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your isoformat strings to `datetime` objects first, change timezones to UTC and then stringify back.
If you are on python 3.7, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182075/how-to-convert-a-timezone-aware-string-to-datetime-in-python-without-dateutil), you can use `fromisoformat` method of `datetime`, but if you don't, like me, I think the best option involves the use of `dateutil` module (you have to install it) and `pytz`:

```
import datetime as dt
from dateutil import parser
import pytz

time_list = ['2016-10-01T00:00:00+01:00','2016-10-01T23:00:00+00:00','2016-10-01T22:00:00+02:00']
utc_time_list = [parser.parse(x).astimezone(pytz.utc).isoformat() for x in time_list]

print(utc_time_list)
['2016-09-30T23:00:00+00:00', '2016-10-01T23:00:00+00:00', '2016-10-01T20:00:00+00:00']
```

Comment: Yea, thanks - thanks exactly what I ended up using. I am not on 3.7 (on 3.5.3) but it still works as expected.