# How do I parse a string date and return a datetime object converted in my system's timezone?

Tags: python-3.x, timezone, python-datetime

I have a date string here `"2019-08-24T08:00:00-04:00"`
and I want to parse it on my system's timezone in python.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
   new Date("2019-08-24T08:00:00-04:00");
```

- this one returns **`Sun Aug 25 2019 00:25:00 GMT+0800`** (Singapore Standard Time) w/c is what I wanted

**PYTHON**

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse as parseDate

parseDate("2019-08-24T08:00:00-04:00")
```

- this one returns `datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 24, 8, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))`

so the other one is August 25 on JS, on python its August 24

Comment: So which one is like your systems time, Javascript or Python one ?

Comment: the javascript one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182075/how-to-convert-a-timezone-aware-string-to-datetime-in-python-without-dateutil