# How to minus time that received from API server and current time in Python

Tags: python, time, iso8601

Kindly help below my query:

I got an estimated time from API server like below:
`2019-09-25T20:11:23+08:00`

it seems like iso 8601 standard with timezone.

I would like to know how to calculate how many days, hours, minutes and seconds left from above value to the current time.

```
import datetime

Receved_time_frim_API = "2019-09-25T20:11:23+08:00"
Current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

left_days = 
left_hour =
left_min =
left_sec =
```

Comment: Please also show the attempts you've made to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time string contains timezone info. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13182163/12112986 it's easy to convert it to datetime object in python 3.7

```
import datetime
received = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(Receved_time_frim_API)
```

In previous versions there is no easy oneliner to convert string with timezone to datetime object. If you're using earlier python version, you can try something crude, like

```
>>> date, timezone = Receved_time_frim_API.split("+")
>>> tz_hours, tz_minutes = timezone.split(":")
>>> date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
>>> date -= datetime.timedelta(hours=int(tz_hours))
>>> date -= datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(tz_minutes))
```

Note that this will work only in case of positive timezones

To substract two datetime objects use

```
td = date - Current_time
left_days = td.days
left_hour = td.seconds // 3600
left_min = (td.seconds//60)%60
left_sec = td.seconds % 60
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick research

Comment: Now as I think about it, if the timezone is positive hours should be substracted from the date. Ive adjusted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay first you need to parse the `Receved_time_frim_API` into datetime format:

```
from dateutil import parser
Receved_time_frim_API = parser.parse("2019-09-25T20:11:23+08:00")
```

But you can't just substract this from your `Current_time`, because `datetime.now()` is not aware of a timezone:

```
from datetime import timezone
Current_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
print (Current_time-Receved_time_frim_API)
```

The result is a `datetime.timedelta`

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick research