# Handling timezone in panda to_datetime function

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

There are already a lot of questions about that topic, but I could not find replies that solve my troubles.

**1. The context**

I have timestamps stored in a list as strings, which look like:

```
print(my_timestamps)
...
3     Sun Mar 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100
4     Sun Mar 31 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0100
5     Sun Mar 31 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0200
6     Sun Mar 31 2019 04:00:00 GMT+0200
...
13    Sun Oct 27 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0200
14    Sun Oct 27 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0200
15    Sun Oct 27 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0100
16    Sun Oct 27 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0100
17    Sun Oct 27 2019 04:00:00 GMT+0100
Name: date, dtype: object
```

You will notice I have kept 2 zones where there are DST.
I use to_datetime() to store it as timestamps in a panda dataframe

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_timestamps)
print(df)
...
3     2019-03-31 00:00:00-01:00
4     2019-03-31 01:00:00-01:00
5     2019-03-31 03:00:00-02:00
6     2019-03-31 04:00:00-02:00
...
13    2019-10-27 01:00:00-02:00
14    2019-10-27 02:00:00-02:00
15    2019-10-27 02:00:00-01:00
16    2019-10-27 03:00:00-01:00
17    2019-10-27 04:00:00-01:00
Name: date, dtype: object
```

A 1st surprising (to me) thing is that 'date' column keeps its dtype as 'object' and not 'datetime64'.

When I want to use these timestamps as indexes with

```
df.set_index('date', inplace = True, verify_integrity = True)
```

I get an error with verify_integrity check informing me there are duplicate indexes.

```
ValueError: Index has duplicate keys: Index([2019-10-27 02:00:00-01:00, 2019-10-27 03:00:00-01:00], dtype='object', name='date')
```

I obviously would like to solve that.

**2. What I tried**

My understanding is that the timezone data is not used, and that to use it, I should try to convert the timestamps to have its dtype to 'datetime64'.

I first added the flag utc=True in to_datetime.

```
test = pd.to_datetime(my_timestamps,utc=True)
```

But then, I simply don't understand the result:

```
...
3    2019-03-31 01:00:00+00:00
4    2019-03-31 02:00:00+00:00
5    2019-03-31 05:00:00+00:00
6    2019-03-31 06:00:00+00:00
...
13   2019-10-27 03:00:00+00:00
14   2019-10-27 04:00:00+00:00
15   2019-10-27 03:00:00+00:00
16   2019-10-27 04:00:00+00:00
17   2019-10-27 05:00:00+00:00
```

According my understanding, timezone has been interpreted in a reversed manner ?!

```
3     Sun Mar 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

shifted in UTC time should read as

```
3     2019-03-30 23:00:00+00:00
```

but here it is translated into:

```
3    2019-03-31 01:00:00+00:00
```

This likely explains then the error of duplicate timestamps appearing

```
14   2019-10-27 04:00:00+00:00
...
16   2019-10-27 04:00:00+00:00
```

Please, has anyone any idea how to correctly handle the timezone information so that it doesn't lead to duplicate Index?

I thank you in advance for your help.

Have a good day,
Bests,

Pierrot

PS: I am fine with having the timestamps expressed in UTC, as long as the shift in hour is correctly managed.

**3. Edit**

It would seem fromisoformat() function, new in Python 3.7, could help. However, it accepts as input a string. I am not certain how it can be used in a "vectorized" manner to apply it on a complete dataframee column.

[How to convert a timezone aware string to datetime in python without dateutil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182075/how-to-convert-a-timezone-aware-string-to-datetime-in-python-without-dateutil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there does be a trouble in dateutil as indicated above.
I reversed +/- sign in my original data file as indicated here:

[How to replace a sub-string conditionally in a pandas dataframe column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508962/how-to-replace-a-sub-string-conditionally-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column)

Bests,
Pierrot