# What is the format of that datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, iso8601

I have that datetime : `2021-10-12T16:00:00.000+02:00` so I tried that :

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-10-12T16:00:00.000+02:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

But it does not work I got that

```
ValueError: time data '2021-10-12T16:00:00.000+02:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a timezone aware string to datetime in Python without dateutil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182075/how-to-convert-a-timezone-aware-string-to-datetime-in-python-without-dateutil)

Answer (score 3):

This is an ISO date. The easiest way to parse it is to call `fromisoformat`.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2021-10-12T16:00:00.000+02:00")       
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 12, 16, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-10-12T16:00:00.000+02:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

You're formatting it wrong.

1. You have milliseconds too, so there is a `%f` separated by a `.`
2. The time zone is formatted as `Z`; it has to be `%z`

Answer (score -2):

```
from datetime import datetime
today=datetime.now() /// 2021-06-25 07:58:56.550604
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") /// 25/06/2021 07:58:56
```

Comment: how is this supposed to answer the question? it doesn't even consider the format in question