# ISO time conversion from a string (Conditions at local time 09:18 on 23 October 2018)

Tags: python, time, beautifulsoup

I am scrapping data from a web where time has been defined in this format **Conditions at local time 09:18 on 23 October 2018** . Based on the given format i want to convert it in ISO format.

To get rid of extra text i followed this approach:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(homePage.content, 'html.parser')
time1 = soup.find("caption")
time2 = time1.get_text().split()
filtter = ["Conditions", "at", "local", "time", "on"]
for m in  time2:
#print(m)
if m not in filtter:
    test = m
    print(test.split)
```

Result of this code is below:

```
09:24
23
October
2018
```

Can anyone guide me here?

Thanks

Comment: This may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460698/python-convert-date-to-iso-8601

Comment: Thank you for help