# How I can reformat dates to ISO format in my code?

Tags: python, json

I have a function which get data from database and reformat they in JSON file, but I need date fields was a ISO format - "dt": "2022-12-01T00:00:00". In code this fields named 'dt'.

```
    def table_to_json():
        db_connect = Database('database_name')
        query = '''SELECT * FROM table_name'''
        data = db_connect.get_query_result(query).fetchall()
        res = {'fields': {'data': []}}
        for obj in data:
            res['fields']['data'].append(
                {
                            'field_1': obj[1],
                            'dt': obj[0],
                            'field_2': obj[2],
                            'field_3': obj[3],
                            'field_4': obj[4],
                            'field_5': obj[5]
                        }
            )
    
        with open("my_file.json", "w") as file:
            json.dump(res, file)
```

Im tryed use `datetime.isoformat(obj[0])`, but dates is str objects and `isoformat()` working with int and datetime formats how i understand.

Comment: You may need to parse it into a date first. Does your database driver return in native Python form, or just as a string?

Comment: To convert a string to a `datetime`, you can either use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)  if the format is fixed or [`python-dateutil`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/2.7.0/) if it's more free format.

Comment: я сделал! я просто использовал 'dt': datetime.strptime(obj[0], '%Y-%m-%d').isoformat(),

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Convert string representation of date to ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460698/python-convert-string-representation-of-date-to-iso-8601)